# Change Array Key With Another Array Key Value PHP

Tags: php, arrays

The array which I want to change the main key value is $files[] and it looks like

```
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => ars-101-sef--toplanti-koltugu-JP1L68UJ.jpg
    [3] => ars-102-mIsafIr-koltugu-UV9H65DX.jpg
    [4] => ars-103-mIsafIr-koltugu-u-ayak-HS3B98DR.jpg
)
```

But I want the main key to change with slug[] array's value which looks like

```
[0] => ares
[1] => ares2
[2] => argon
[3] => argon2
[4] => argon3
[5] => beren
[6] => beren2
[7] => beta
```

so the first one will be

```
[ares] => Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => ars-101-sef--toplanti-koltugu-JP1L68UJ.jpg
    [3] => ars-102-mIsafIr-koltugu-UV9H65DX.jpg
    [4] => ars-103-mIsafIr-koltugu-u-ayak-HS3B98DR.jpg
)
```

and the rest will go like that. How can achive that? Thank you

Comment: You can loop your first array and check the index in second array get the value and assign a new associative mulidimensional array with the index got from second array as key with same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = [
    [
        '.',
        '..',
        'ars-101-sef--toplanti-koltugu-JP1L68UJ.jpg',
    ],
    [
        '.',
        '..',
        'ars-101-sef--toplanti-koltugu-JP1L68UJ.jpg',
    ],
    [
        '.',
        '..',
        'ars-101-sef--toplanti-koltugu-JP1L68UJ.jpg',
    ],
];
$slug = [
    'ares',
    'ares2',
    'argon',
];
print_r(array_combine($slug, $files));
```

Demo [here](https://3v4l.org/JA0sl).

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you also help me to delete the arrays element's which is

'.',
'..',

Comment: Iterate over elements and use `unset`. Also it's better to ask another question and show how your get you data with filepaths.

Answer (score 0):

Check this also, how you will get the same without using **array_combine**. And by using **foreach** loop.

```
 $files = [
    [
        '.',
        '..',
        'ars-101-sef--toplanti-koltugu-JP1L68UJ.jpg',
    ],
    [
        '.',
        '..',
        'ars-101-sef--toplanti-koltugu-JP1L68UJ.jpg',
    ],
    [
        '.',
        '..',
        'ars-101-sef--toplanti-koltugu-JP1L68UJ.jpg',
    ],
];
$slug = [
    'ares',
    'ares2',
    'argon',
];

$resultArray = [];
foreach ($files as $key => $item) {
    $appendArray = [];
    foreach ($item as $keyInside => $i) {
        if ($i !== '.' || $i !== '..') {
            $appendArray = $i;
        }
    }
    $resultArray[$slug[$key]] = $appendArray;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($resultArray); die;
```